# Simple game database problems

Tags: c++

NOTE: I am new to C++ and may do things that are bad practice and if you see that please tell me so I can fix that and please don't be mean. I have only started coding 1-2 months ago. And I am still learning. Please be open to the fact I may not know everything.

This is a console text-based game. It works great! Although, I am creating a feature in it to allow the user to drag and drop any amount of other databases on it to allow database transfers. Although this works fine the problem is that I have a little process it will do to try and make sure none of the info in the databases is the same by placing a number to them,

Example there will be 2 profiles 1 in each file. They are both named main. Then the user drags the second database onto the game and it loads that database into the original one. But now becuase there are 2 SIMILAR profile names it won't be able to differentiate which is which. So then it goes through a little function which scans the database and places a number in front of the copies. Starting at 5 and working its way up. Although this would seem to work and not be that hard to actually do I have hit a problem and I do not know what is wrong. I do know however it is something with how it scans for duplicates. Please help.

I have tried for like a whole day trying different methods or re-writing the code. Google has not revealed a lot to me.

I am using the following libraries in my code. (Some might not be used in the example but tbh I don't remember which is directly used in THIS function).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <functional>
#include <fstream>
```

Here is the scanning function to make sure there are no duplicate profiles.

Let me explain what happens.
I make a ton of variables which are used in the database. As you can see inside of the database it has a certain order.

Using file stream I access the database. (I have a function which will combine all the databases the user dragged in and the current profiles and data which works just fine).

The pattern in the database looks something like this.

profile_name user_name 100 3 0 0 0 0 knight 1 100 0 0

profile      name      health etc

If you look at the variables you will see the technical order.

```
void scanCopy()
{
    std::string profile{ "John's_Profile" };
    std::string name{ "John_Doe" };
    int health{ 0 };
    int damage{ 0 };
    int gold{ 0 };
    int exp{ 0 };
    int level{ 0 };
    int score{ 0 };
    std::string CLASS{ "null" };
    int dungeon{ 0 };
    int maxHealth{ 0 };
    int lives{ 0 };
    int kills{ 0 };

    std::ifstream in("data/database.txt");
    std::vector <std::string> profiles;
    int sizeOfVector{ 0 };
    while (in >> profile >> name >> health >> damage >> gold >> exp >> level >> score >> CLASS >> dungeon >> maxHealth >> lives >> kills)
    {
        profiles.resize(sizeOfVector += 1);
        profiles.at(sizeOfVector - 1) = { profile };
        std::cout << profiles.at(sizeOfVector - 1) << "\n\n";
    }
    in.close();
    for (int loop{ 0 }; loop < sizeOfVector; ++loop)
    {
        int compare{ loop };

        for (int index{ loop }; index < sizeOfVector; ++index)
        {

            if (compare == index)//meaning they are like at profiles(1)and (1)
                continue;
            if (profiles.at(compare) == profiles.at(index))
            {
                std::ofstream out("data/~database.txt", std::ios::app);
                in.open("data/database.txt");
                int nameIndex{ 5 };
                while (in >> profile >> name >> health >> damage >> gold >> exp >> level >> score >> CLASS >> dungeon >> maxHealth >> lives >> kills)
                {
                    if (profile == profiles.at(index))
                    {
                        out << profile << nameIndex << " " << name << " " << health << " " << damage << " " << gold << " " << exp << " " << level << " " << score << " " << CLASS << " " << dungeon << " " << maxHealth << " " << lives << " " << kills << " " << std::endl; //Notice at the start profile is put into the database with an extra variable nameIndex to make its name now unique.
                        ++nameIndex;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        out << profile << " " << name << " " << health << " " << damage << " " << gold << " " << exp << " " << level << " " << score << " " << CLASS << " " << dungeon << " " << maxHealth << " " << lives << " " << kills << " " << std::endl;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    in.close();
    remove("data/database.txt");
    in.open("data/~database.txt");
    std::ofstream out("data/database.txt", std::ios::app);

       //A buffer to copy everything inside a file to a string.
    std::string upData((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in)),
        (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
    /////
    if (out)
        out << upData; //putting everything in the tmp file to the file named database.txt
    out.close();
    in.close();
    remove("data/~database.txt");
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

The problem is that it does not do its job. It will put numbers by anything. Besides that, it will also seem to overflow or something. What it does is after you already dragged something in, it pretends to work. Then any more input from dragging it does not get scanned. Thing is that everything is copied from the files the user drags from the database to a tmp file. Then the database is deleted and the temp file is renamed to database.txt. The problem is that this whole scan function seems to not be working right and I don't see the problem in it. Does anyone know a good way to do something like this or what the problem is? Thanks!

Comment: "I have only started coding 1-2 months ago. And I am still learning. Please be open to the fact I may not know everything." - Given the complexity and difficulty of C++, expect that to be the situation for at least the next 5 or so years (that is, if you use the language on a daily basis and study on the side - otherwise more) (in my experience). I'm about 20+ years in (daily the past 10-15 or so) and I still don't know all the tricky corners.

Comment: We really do not need the backstory that this is a game, that users can do XYZ and so on. Please construct a **minimal** example, as in [mcve]. Often by constructing those you yourself discover the problem.

Comment: What if an user puts in a name containing blanks?

Comment: It won't let you. And if you somehow bypass it will make your name John_Doe. It will actually encrypt the databases to prevent that. But in anycase, it would not receive blank input well. It puts _ for spaces by scanning your input.

Comment: @Fureeish Thank you for the feedback. I will try to narrow things down. I made it descriptive becuase I do not know the problem so I wanted to include all the information I could to help diagnose the problem. But I will take that into account. in the future and right now.

Comment: @Annonymous I think you'd be best off spending your time learning how to use a debugger. The code is fairly simple and a debugging session will quickly find the problem.

Comment: @Annonymous Plus, always, always check that you open files successfully, every program that you write. Even if they open now, 6 months down the line they'll fail and you'll be glad you added the code to catch that error.

Comment: I know how to debug although the user has to put input and I can't do that in debugging. (I don't know how). (The user has to drag files ONTO the game otherwise it will just load the game like normal). If there is a way to in a way debug the program after giving it input from dragging something onto the application that would be great. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Yes It is robust. I made sure to do that although in this function I deleted them for simplicity. Thanks for the note.

Comment: You said it's "a console text-based game". So where does mouse-dragging come into it? Confused.

Comment: There is no mouse dragging. I am sorry I may have been confusing. I mean dragging files through command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

We really do not need the backstory that this is a game, that users can do XYZ and so on. Please construct a minimal example, as in minimal reproducible example. Often by constructing those, you yourself discover the problem. – Fureeish

Thank you Fureeish. I have found the problem. I was sending the function too many times which wiped the file or it did not scan it all the way. It is hard to explain the real thing I did because it was easy but I can't explain it well.

ALL IN ALL. I examined and found the bug, I was sending it to this function I posted up there too many times. or too little times.

Comment: Happy to help :>